# Different layouts based on screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement - For one particular screen size (say 10 inches), there are two Fragment within an activity - Fragment A and Fragment B.

For all other screen sizes greater than 10 inches, Fragment A and Fragment B are combined as one Fragment(say Fragment C).

How we can achieve this in Android?

Comment: Greater than 10 inch or less than 10 inch? This seems wrong.

Comment: There are very few >10 inch devices out there.  They exist, but they did poorly in the market.  Are you sure you don't mean 10 inch vs smaller?

Comment: There are devices greater than 10 inches..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is

- First change dimensions of fragment A as per ssp and sdp
- Then change dimensions of fragment B as per ssp and sdp
- Now change screen division dimensions of fragment C as per ssp and sdp 
  (To merge fragment A and fragement B)

Links to do this:

https://github.com/intuit/ssp

https://github.com/intuit/sdp